# Facebook Open Graph tags not showing when sharing

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have added the appropriate OG Meta tags to my page (http://yorkschool.korkoladesign.com).

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Prospectus"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="article"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://yorkschool.korkoladesign.com/index.php"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://yorkschool.korkoladesign.com/application/files/2914/4908/7529/The_York_School.JPG"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="The York School"/>
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="************"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="Test - Our faculty embodies the qualities we hope to inspire in our students: empathy, responsiveness, inventiveness, insight and critical thinking."/>
```

When I use the OG Object Debugger, it grabs the correct info for each property but when I look at the "When shared..." section, none of this info is there. It still uses the same default info that was present before I added the OG tags. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the facebook debug tool to fetch your new meta information. Go to https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ enter your URL and click "Fetch new scrape information" to refresh all meta data.

Comment: That's my problem. I am using the Debug Tool but when I "Fetch new scrape information" to refresh all meta data, it doesn't work. Give it a try with my URL and you'll see what I mean. 

It grabs the raw tags like the og:title, og:image, etc but when you go a little further down and look at the "When shared, this is what will be included" section, it shows only the auto populated info. This info is what would be added even if I hadn't included any meta tags. There seems to be some sort of disconnect here.

Comment: I'm having same problem. Debug tool not getting graph information.
Here's my debug address: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fhorizonteacores.com%2Fdesporto%2Fartigo%2F55